# Append rows in array

Tags: python, arrays

I am making a [Draughts game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts) in python, I made an array 10 by 10 and I need to append values within the entire row so that is eventually looks like this;

```
(
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2],
[2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
[0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2],
[2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
)
```

Here is my attempt at it so far, I know it's incorrect;

```
__author__ = 'Matt'

import array
Board_Array = array(10, 10)

pieces = ['Empty', 'White_Piece', 'Black_Piece', 'Upgraded_White_Piece', 'Upgraded_Black_Piece']
list(enumerate(pieces))

if Board_Array.array_equals == [1, 0]:
    for i in range(10):
        if (i%2) == 0:
            array.pop([i])
            array.insert(i,1)
```

Comment: Without referring to the code (which you really can't, since you're asking for it to be corrected), perhaps you could explain what is the pattern that is supposed to be in your array. There are 0s, 1s, and 2s. It started off with a board with what pattern? You need to transform it into a larger board with what pattern?

Comment: I get some nifty `TypeErrors` here. Did you ever both to test this? Also, you can just use the built-in `list`, no need for something else...

Comment: @AmiTavory the value of a white piece is 1 and a black piece is 2 and empty pieces are 0, so I am trying to populate the board with white and black pieces

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [nested list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [173]: [[((i+j) % 2)*k for i in range(10)] for k in (1,1,0,2,2) 
           for j in (0,1)]
Out[173]: 
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2],
 [2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2],
 [2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0]]
```

This is equivalent to

```
result = []
for k in (1,1,0,2,2):
    for j in (0,1):
        row = []
        for i in range(10):
            row.append(((i+j) % 2)*k)
        result.append(row)
```